# Help finding title of book about planets containing essays and sf stories

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, planets, solar-system

Ok, this one has been bugging me for a while now. Back in, I would say the mid-80's, I owned a hardcover book with a white dust jacket featuring a full-color photo of Saturn. I thought it was called 'The Planets' or 'The Solar System', but I haven't been able to find it under those titles. The book had one section for each planet, consisting of a nonfiction essay and a science fiction short story based on that planet. I remember in particular that Bradbury's ["All Summer in a Day"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_summer_in_a_day) was the featured story in the Venus section, but the book doesn't seem to be in the [IFSDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58363) list for that story. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you already considered and rejected [The Planets](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?45387), edited by Byron Preiss and published in 1985?  It seems to be a partial match for your recollections.  It's got one essay and one short story per planet - but the Bradbury is "The Love Affair", and it's for Mars; and although one of the covers has a full-colour Saturn, the background is black, not white.

[image] [image]

Comment: That's it exactly! It's hard to tell from the image on the right, but the white border around the black actually extended to the spine and back of the dustcover. I could have _sworn_ that I was right about the Bradbury story, but obviously not. Thank you!